# Fibonacci with recursion steps shown indented / nested

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86, fibonacci, irvine32

This is the format that I need:

```
F(3) = F(2) + F(1) =
  F(2) = (F1) + F(0) =
    F(1) = 1
    F(0) = 1   
  F(2) = 1   
  F(1) = 1 
F(3) = 2
```

and this is my code, how am I going to do to get the format I want?
Please give me a hint or something that may help, thank you. I just start learning assembly language. 
I only know how to show the first line like f()= the answer, but don't know how to show the process.

```
    .data
    fib1 BYTE "f(",0
    fib2 BYTE ") + f(",0
    fib3 BYTE ") = ",0
    intVal DWORD ?

    main PROC

    mov edx, OFFSET fib1    ;show f(intVal)=
    call WriteString
    mov edx, intVal
    call WriteDec
    mov edx, OFFSET fib3
    call WriteString

    mov ecx, intVal-1       
    push intVal
    call fib
    add esp, 4



    call WriteDec           ;show result
    call crlf

    mov edx, OFFSET msg5        ;show goodbye msg
    call WriteString
    mov edx, OFFSET username
    call WriteString    
    exit 
    main ENDP



       fib PROC c
    add ecx, 1
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp,4               
    mov eax, [ebp+8]        ;get value

    cmp eax,2               ;if ((n=1)or(n=2))
    je S4
    cmp eax,1
    je S4

    dec eax                 ;do fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
    push eax                ;fib(n-1)
    call fib
    mov [ebp-4], eax        ;store first result

    dec dword ptr [esp]     ;(n-1) -> (n-2)
    call fib
    add esp,4           ;clear

    add eax,[ebp-4]     ;add result and stored first result

    jmp Quit
S4:
    mov eax,1           ;start from 1,1

Quit: 
    mov esp,ebp         ;restore esp
            pop ebp             ;restore ebp

            ret
        fib ENDP

        END main
```

Comment: What is causing you problem? PS: don't post code as image.

Comment: Please add your code directly to your questions instead of using an image. Also see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Assuming this is for a class, please post an actual example of assembly code that you have done so far, even if it doesn't include the Fibonacci part. The "format you need" shows a recurrence relation. This could be implemented with either a loop or recursion (a function that calls itself). You need to find out if either method will be acceptable or what's probably the case here if recursion is the goal for this assignment.

Comment: @rcgldr: It's not acceptable here, which is why that link contains a nice explanation of exactly why *not*, and advice on how to fix it, and tells people that downvotes are usually prepared to *remove* their downvote after the problem is fixed.  If people don't read the rules ([ask] and [mcve]) or look at examples of good questions before posting, they should expect downvotes if they broke any of the major rules that they didn't bother to learn.

Comment: Looks like your best bet is a recursive implementation that passes a "column" arg, so it knows what column to print on and you can get that recursive indented output format.

Comment: @rcgldr That's why I linked a nicely written text explaining why it is not useful in this forum.

Comment: I'm sorry posting code as image, that won't happen again, thanks.

Comment: I manually typed in your other image too. That is the kind of format we need. No one likes to click on an unknown *external* link, especially if it might be dead, after a while. Put all the necessary info in your question, if you can.

Comment: @fuz - the images in the question have been replaced by text now. I'll delete this comment later.

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to output a "newline" at the end of each line of output, which could be a carriage return (00dh) followed by a linefeed (00ah) or just a linefeed (00ah) depending on the system (I don't know the irvine setup).

The indented lines should be printed from within the fib function, which means you have to save (push/pop stack) any registers that the print functions use.

The fib function needs to print out a variable number of spaces depending on the level of recursion, based on the text, 2 spaces per level of recursion.

The fib function needs to handle an input of 0 and return 0.

Note that the number of recursive calls to the fib function will be 2 * fib(n) - 1, assuming fib checks for fib(0), fib(1), fib(2) (more if it doesn't check for fib(2) ), which would be 5.94 billion calls for fib(47) = 2971215073, the max value for 32 bit unsigned integers. You may want to limit inputs to something like fib(10) = 55 or fib(11) = 89 or fib(12) = 144.